# CakePHP nice urls - how to prevent normal urls from working

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, url-rewriting, google-index

I have a website that's written using CakePHP. I've added some rewrite rules in the .htacces file to change the default urls to different ones (instead of /controller1/action1/parameter I have /some-string-about-controller-and-action/parameter, for example).

The problem is that now both the normal url and the nice one are available, and google seems to be indexing both, which is a problem. I'd like to only keep the nice one, which is the proper way to handle this so that it affects the google results as little as possible?

Comment: You've changed it in .htaccess? Why not use cake's own routing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't want to use cakes own routing (if you are having trouble doing what you want, you can accomplish what you want with a custom route class), then make sure that you redirect all relevant URL's in your .htaccess file to the desired URL using a MOVED PERMANENTLY redirect.

This way google will index the target url instead of the one that is undesirable. You are right to take offense to this, double indexing is a great way to harm your SEO rankings.